# how to show child pages of one parent on all pages wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show the child pages of rugs in the footer in all pages on my wordpress site.

the code in the footer i am using is

```
            <?php
        global $wp_query;
        $post = $wp_query->post;
        $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
        if( empty($post->post_parent) ) {
            $parent = $post->ID;
        } else {
            $parent = end($ancestors);
        }
        if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&echo=0" )) { ?>

        <ul class="footerNav clearfix">
            <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=$parent&depth=1" ); ?>
        </ul><!-- #secondary-nav -->

        <?php } ?>
```

however this only shows the child pages in the footer when you are in the relevant catagory, I would like to see this navigation on all pages.

Thanks,

Sat

here is the link to a page with the footer how i'd like it on all pages

http://satbulsara.com/luke-irwin/rugs/new-in/fishy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
$post = $wp_query->post;
$ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post);
```

the variable *$post* is assigned the post the visitor is currently viewing.

If you want a menu of all childs of *rugs* on all pages, you only need the bottom part of your code. Also, the *child_of* parameter needs not be assigned via variable, you can input the static page ID of *rugs*, i.e. *173*:

```
<ul class="footerNav clearfix">
    <?php wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=173&depth=1&sort_column=post_name" ); ?>
</ul><!-- #secondary-nav -->
```

These three lines will suffice in generating the menu for you. The *if* statement you have around it checks whether a the specific parent page has children and only generates an unordered list if that is the case. Since you know it exists in this case, I'd leave it out and save those two lines. I have included the *sort_column* parameter for sake of completeness - this would give you an alphabetically sorted menu of all rugs.

The code above the *if* statement is only needed for dynamic menus that change depending on the page the visitor is currently on. Should you ever want to implement such a menu, I'd still go about it differently and think the above is bloated. Simply inserting

```
<?php $ancestors = get_post_ancestors($post); ?>
```

into your *header.php* file will let you generate dynamic menus elsewhere with

```
<?php if (is_page(173) || in_array(173,$ancestors)) { ?>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=173&depth=1'); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

As said above, for your particular case, the fist code block three-liner is sufficient.

Further reference: [WP Codex: wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

Comment: hi i changed it to $ancestors = $ancestors = get_post_ancestors(175);

Comment: I made a tired thinking error. The code I gave you yesterday grabs the ancestors of '_rugs_' - i.e. your home page (slug '_luke-irwin_'). However, since you've figured out to change that to 175 it would have worked, had you removed the whole `$wp-query` stuff and _if_ statement and just left the `$ancestors = get_post_ancestors(175);` and `$parent = end($ancestors);`

Anyway, I have updated my answer.

Comment: fantastic, thank you for your help so much!! I will test it out later. just in the middle of something else now.